# 2 or more assemblies have the same identity

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, ado.net, assemblies

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and creating a Windows Form in C#. Yesterday, development was going fine, i was working on connecting an access database to my datagrid. it worked several times, however when i made a new connection and tried to run it again (F5), i got a ton of errors, so a narrowed it down by deleting (and undoing) my data sources and the error still exists. This is it...

> Warning   1   The type 'Wincent_Warehouse_Management_Studios.Form1' in 'C:\Users\Wilson Kao\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios\Form1.Designer.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'Wincent_Warehouse_Management_Studios.Form1'
>
> Warning   7   Two or more assemblies have the same identity 'Wincent Warehouse Management Studios, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, ProcessorArchitecture=x86'.  Wincent Warehouse Management Studios
>
> Warning   8   Two or more files have the same target path 'C:\Users\Wilson Kao\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios\bin\Debug\Wincent Warehouse Management Studios.exe'.   Wincent Warehouse Management Studios

After the warnings, it gave me this error...

> No Source Available
> No Symbols are loaded for any stackframe. The source code could not be displayed

I can sort of see the problem but I'm not too sure how to solve it... I know in my program somewhere (and not my own code) I am including something that causes my program to conflict. So what I tried was I went to the bin/debug folder and deleted everything in it... and it worked. However, after the files in that directory were replenished, I got the same problem again. I'm in some desperate need for help and any sort of clue where to go will be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Spaces?  In an executable name?  First thing I'd do is strip those spaces out of EVERY identifier within your solution.  Every single one, from output names down through every underscore you can find.  Secondly, it seems like you're referencing your own assembly.  Check your References, and make sure you're not pointing to an .exe in your /bin folder or somewhere else.

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your comment. I'll try to get rid of the spaces. As for references, do you know where I can find where they're pointing to? (new to visual studio) Thanks!

Comment: Problem Solved. I disabled ClickOnce Security and it's working now (with the exception of error one). You do this by going to your project properties and then going to the security tab. awesome thanks for anyone reading this

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me but I'm using **VB** in VS 2010 Pro.

I have had a similar warning  "Two or more files have the same target path ..."  along with "Two or more assemblies have the same identity....." this has occurred after publishing my project, with the ClickOnce Security enabled.

The fix that worked for me was:

1. Open the project properties dialog, Properties > "projectname" Properties
2. Open the "publish" tab. Select "Application Files"
3. I had two entries for my projects "exe" file EG:- Accounts.exe. Pick one of the duplicates select the "Publish Status" drop down select "Exclude"
4. Then click "Publish Now"

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me crazy today & your steps fixed it for me.